# How to find less than or equal to of 3072 data in python data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several data in a column of dataframe in string format,

```
Free disk space
158168
266340
16
```

How to find out out the data in the dataframe less than 3072.

I have tried the following code, but dataframe is coming 0 value.

```
df['Free Disk Space']=pd.to_numeric(df['Free Disk Space']).between(0, 3072, inclusive=False)
```

but  true and false  is showing, instead of less than  or equal to 3072 data .

Any one can help me pls.

Thank you

Comment: You need to attach a sample of your data here

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try: `df[pd.to_numeric(df['Free disk space']) <= 3072]`. See the section [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

[`Series.between(left, right)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) compares series value with left and right value, thus it returns boolean value.

You need further do boolean indexing to filter the dataframe or series:

```
out = df['Free Disk Space'][pd.to_numeric(df['Free Disk Space']).between(0, 3072, inclusive=False)]
# above way is better to write as follow 
out = df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df['Free Disk Space']).between(0, 3072, inclusive=False), 'Free Disk Space']
```

You can also use [`DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to filter the DataFrame.